# Is the use of logical comparisons quicker than axes in XPath?

Tags: performance, xpath, comparison, axes

I have the an XML document that will balloon in size as time goes on and I would like to ensure that my XPath choice for an XSL `select` will be as efficient as possible.

The document contains the following types of elements:

```
<simple_instance>
  <name>Class0</name>
  <type>Business_Capability</type>
  <own_slot_value>
    <slot_reference>contained_business_capabilities</slot_reference>
    <value value_type="simple_instance">Class1</value>
    <value value_type="simple_instance">Class3</value>
    <value value_type="simple_instance">Class4</value>
    <value value_type="simple_instance">Class5</value>
  </own_slot_value>
  <own_slot_value>
    <slot_reference>business_capability_level</slot_reference>
    <value value_type="string">1</value>
  </own_slot_value>
  <own_slot_value>
    <slot_reference>name</slot_reference>
    <value value_type="string">Planning</value>
  </own_slot_value>
</simple_instance>
```

Which of these two selectors (which find elements like the one above) will be more efficient in the long run?

`/node()/simple_instance[type='Business_Capability']/own_slot_value/slot_reference[text()='business_capability_level']/following-sibling::value[text()='1']`

or

`/node()/simple_instance[type='Business_Capability' and (own_slot_value/slot_reference='business_capability_level') and (own_slot_value/value='1')]`

My guess is that, if the implementation of XML short-circuits the `and`, the latter will be quicker.

Note:  I'm using Protege's XML/XSL capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The two XPath expressions have different results, so asking which is faster seems irrelevant (the first selects a value element, the second a simple_instance element).

In addition, XPath is a specification not an implementation. Implementations differ widely in their strategies for evaluating complex paths. An answer that is true for one implementation may well not be true for another. Measure it and see (and tell us the answer).